# how to update data in multiple lists Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

. update the data given a list of most recent miles figures,
removing the oldest miles figure for each place

```
data People= People{ person:: String, age:: Int, weigth:: Float, miles:: [Float]} 

testData :: [People]
testData = [ person "sara"       19  50   [ 5, 8, 8],
          person "ed"      50  60   [0 , 1, 2],
          person "norman"      25   75     [ 2, 3 ,5]]
```

I am trying to take away all last digits and add new digits to each list given **[2,1,5]** 
so i will then have [**[ 2,5,8], [1,0,1], [5,2,3]**] as the new miles for each person

Comment: First format your code, so we can understand something :/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zipWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]`. It uses a helper function to zip two lists together.

First, you need to define this helper, that takes a `People` and a `Float` and returns an updated `People`, e.g.

```
update :: Float -> People -> People
update n people = people { miles = newMiles }
   where newMiles = n : init (miles people)
```

This can be used with `zipWith` like this:

```
zipWith update [2, 1, 5] testData
```

---

Note that your definition of `testData` is incorrect. You have to use the `People` data constructor, like so:

```
testData :: [People]
testData = [ People "sara" 19 50 [5, 8, 8]
           -- etc.
           ]
```

Comment: T%hanks for the correction for the testData definition

Answer (score 1):

So basically you may do as follows;

```
data People = People { person :: String
                     , age    :: Int
                     , weight :: Float
                     , miles  :: [Float]
                     } deriving (Show)

testData :: [People]
testData = [ People "sara"   19 50 [5,8,8]
           , People "ed"     50 60 [0,1,2]
           , People "norman" 25 75 [2,3,5]
           ]

addMiles :: [People] -> [Float] -> [People]
addMiles ps ms = zipWith f ps ms
                 where
                 f p m = p {miles = m : init (miles p)}
```

or you may do like

```
addMiles :: [People] -> [Float] -> [People]
addMiles = zipWith (\p m -> p {miles = m : init (miles p)})
```

Then;

```
addMiles testData [2,1,5]
[ People {person = "sara", age = 19, weight = 50.0, miles = [2.0,5.0,8.0]}
, People {person = "ed", age = 50, weight = 60.0, miles = [1.0,0.0,1.0]}
, People {person = "norman", age = 25, weight = 75.0, miles = [5.0,2.0,3.0]}
]
```